# How to access http source of spring cloud data flow server in a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud-dataflow

I started Spring Cloud Dataflow server with the provided `docker-compose.yaml` file and defined a simple stream: `http | log`

Now I'd like send some data to the http source from my host computer, but I'm unable to find the correct server address and port.

I'd like to

```
curl -X POST -d 'data to be sent' http://localhost:8080
```

What do I have to use for `http://localhost:8080` to get this working?

This is my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7
    expose:
      - "5672"
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    expose:
      - "2181"
  dataflow-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq
      - spring.cloud.skipper.client.serverUri=http://skipper-server:7577/api
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.influx.enabled=true
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.influx.db=myinfluxdb
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.management.metrics.export.influx.uri=http://influxdb:8086
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.grafana-info.url=http://localhost:3000
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - /Users/ernst/Temp/scdf:/root/apps
  app-import:
    image: springcloud/openjdk:latest
    depends_on:
      - dataflow-server
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "
        while ! nc -z dataflow-server 9393;
        do
          sleep 1;
        done;
        wget -qO- 'http://dataflow-server:9393/apps' --post-data='uri=http://bitt.ly/Einstein-SR2-stream-applications-rabbit-maven&force=true';
        echo 'Stream apps imported'
        wget -qO- 'http://dataflow-server:9393/apps' --post-data='uri=http://bitt.ly/Dearborn-SR1-task-applications-maven&force=true';
        echo 'Task apps imported'"
  skipper-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:${SKIPPER_VERSION:?SKIPPER_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: skipper
    ports:
    - "7577:7577"
    - "9000-9010:9000-9010"
    volumes:
      - /Users/ernst/Temp/scdf:/root/apps
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:1.7.4
    container_name: 'influxdb'
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'

  grafana:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-grafana-influxdb:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: 'grafana'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
volumes:
  scdf-targets:
```

Comment: I'm not a specialist with Spring Cloud Dataflow and this might be a stupid question, but which service in the above docker-compose exposes the HTTP endpoint you want to reach with CURL?

Comment: No, that's not a stupid question! It took me some time to find that it's `skipper-server` and not `dataflow-server`.

Answer (score 1):

The java applications that make up the streams in Spring Cloud Data Flow are executed in the `skipper-server` container defined in the `docker-composer.yaml`.

This means the port mapping in the skipper-server section is relevant:

```
  skipper-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:${SKIPPER_VERSION:?SKIPPER_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: skipper
    ports:
    - "7577:7577"
    - "9000-9010:9000-9010"
```

This means ports 7577 and 9000-9010 are mapped to host ports.

To prevent the `http` source to pick a random port the stream definition must look like this:

```
http --server.port=9000 | log
```

So now the following works fine:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":"1","temperature":"100"}' http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: It was a pleasure to be your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)